# installing GATTlib for Pybluez?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth

I try to run the Bluetooth Low Energy examples on the raspberry pi using PyBluez.

All the examples require the gattlib module. I get the error

```
from gattlib import *
ImportError: No module named gattlib
```

I tried to install it:

```
pip3 install gattlib
```

but this doesn't work? I can't install gattlib?

---

Edit: This is the output when installing gattlib:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install gattlib
Collecting gattlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/2f/5b1aecec551b42b59d8b399ad444b5672972efb590ca83d784dbe616a3e1/gattlib-0.20150805.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'glib-2.0' found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-p365j80d/gattlib/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        "pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0".split()).decode('utf-8')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--cflags', 'glib-2.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-p365j80d/gattlib/
```

Answer (score 5):

Documentation: https://pypi.org/project/gattlib/

Install these depends first:

```
pkg-config
libboost-python-dev
libboost-thread-dev
libbluetooth-dev >= 4.101
libglib2.0-dev
python-dev
```

Then, for `gattlib` with python3, have a try with:

```
pip3 download gattlib
tar xvzf ./gattlib-0.20150805.tar.gz
cd gattlib-0.20150805/
sed -ie 's/boost_python-py34/boost_python-py35/' setup.py
pip3 install .
```

Comment: How to manage this for windows? What are the dependencies? I get error `No matching distributions found for gattlib`.

Comment: if you install the dependences and then run again pip install it works!! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

In linux the way to fix this is

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev libglib2.0-dev python-dev
sudo pip install gattlib
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this too. I think it seems lacking of some dependencies found here:

https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib/src/a858e8626a93cb9b4ad56f3fb980a6517a0702c6/DEPENDS?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

For me even after install them I couldn't success in installation. I used an alternative package:

```
pip3 install pygattlib
```